# Do not include drawableLeft when aligning items

Tags: android, android-layout

I have Two textViews, one under another, like this:

[image]

and this is how it looks from code

```
   <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_some_sign"
        android:text="Some text in here" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="June 2015" />
```

What I want is to move red circle out of alignment, so two views would be aligned only by text.

so it would look like this:

[image]

I can add an `ImageVIew` and it would do the trick, but I'm curious if there is any other way.

Thanks

Comment: How about padding start for bottom text view :D

Comment: @leo I need also include some dummy transparent image in it. Too tricky :D Maybe there is an out of box solution...

Comment: just add extra left padding to june 2015

Comment: Either, use `paddingStart` in bottom text or use `android:translationX="-20dp"` in the top text. Change this `20dp` to your preference.

Answer (score 0):

Use a view or imageView like a red circle shape and two textViews and put them in a constraintLayout like this.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageRedCircle"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageRedCircle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageRedCircle"
        android:text="Some text in here"
        android:id="@+id/textViewSomeText"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageRedCircle"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="June 2015"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/textViewSomeText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textViewSomeText"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two linear layouts. One for red circle and text views. Another for two text views.

```
 <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_red_circle"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Some text in here" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="June 2015" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>
```